# How to configure Linux to cache file metadata in preference to contents?

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache

I’d like to set the system up to use most RAM for file system metadata caching, but only a reasonably small amount for read/write caching and prefetching files. Ideally I would like to be able to browse the filesystem (as much as it fits in the RAM) without spinning up the disks until I actually open a file.

Here are the details:

I have a home-made file server. It’s got five disks in a LVM volume around 9TB, but only 4GB of RAM. Since the server doesn’t do much else then serve files, most of the RAM is used for caching. (“free” reports 3.4G out of 3.9G used for cache.)

The server lives in my bedroom, and if all disks are spinning it makes enough noise to be annoying when it’s quiet. (I don’t mean seek noise, just spinning noise. The disks are of various makes and models, and I think slight differences in rotation speeds cause interference. No disk is noisy on its own, but if some of them are spinning together there’s a slight noise with a sub-Hertz period.) So I configured the server to spin down the disks most of the time.

Of course, if the disks are spun down when I open a folder in my file manager, there’s a delay while whichever of the disks has that folder spins up. Just that is no big deal. But depending on where I look, it can happen several times in a row, if LVM happened to spread the metadata for each subfolder on the different disks.

I suspect that Linux mostly fills its cache with file contents, and possibly prefetched data. The caching isn’t very useful beyond a few MB to ensure smooth playback; if I just watched a movie I probably won’t look at it again anytime soon. Prefetching, if it happens, is also completely useless *in my case*, after more than a few MB.

But one would think that 4GB should be plenty to be able to cache most file-system metadata, at least those parts that were already visited, so that I could browse the files without needing to spin up the disks if it turns out they’re sleeping.

There would still be a delay when opening the file, but that’s OK. Compare “click; *wait*; click; *wait*; click; *wait*; play; watch” with “click; click; click; play; *wait*; watch”. The former is incredibly frustrating; the latter is almost expected.

Notes:

1. Should it matter, the kernel is 3.2, the OS is Debian, the volume is lvm2, and the FS is ext4.
2. The only reason for the spin down is noise during the night; the server is otherwise running continuously. (I made it as low-power as reasonable.) The spin-down delay is varied depending on the time of day.
3. The hard disks are only for media. The OS is on a separate (small) flash drive. (Which means any spin-up delays comes from the data, not just because it needed something in `/usr` or whatever. I could spare a few GB on it if it would help with my problem somehow.
4. A reasonable impact on performance is not a big deal. The disks are faster than my network anyway.

Answer (score 11):

To control how Linux caches things refer to this
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

In particular look at vfs_cache_pressure, you probably want a really low value or maybe even zero (1 sounds a bit safer to me though):

```
vfs_cache_pressure
------------------

Controls the tendency of the kernel to reclaim the memory which is used for
caching of directory and inode objects.

At the default value of vfs_cache_pressure=100 the kernel will attempt to
reclaim dentries and inodes at a "fair" rate with respect to pagecache and
swapcache reclaim.  Decreasing vfs_cache_pressure causes the kernel to prefer
to retain dentry and inode caches. When vfs_cache_pressure=0, the kernel will
never reclaim dentries and inodes due to memory pressure and this can easily
lead to out-of-memory conditions. Increasing vfs_cache_pressure beyond 100
causes the kernel to prefer to reclaim dentries and inodes.
```

Also you may want to modify `swappiness` so that you never swap data or make it so that it only happens in extreme cases.

The `drop_caches` option might be handy for explicitly dropping the data you don't want cached anymore.

I'm sure there are probably other options that may help, so review the kernel documentation.

To apply them I'd put the settings you want to change in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or whatever your OS has to restore them at boot.

Comment: Good post, but you would want as much swapping as feasible given the OP's goal. Swapping only hits user memory so increasing it's tendency to swap out to disk then leaves more physical memory for the caches to take up. Increasing swappiness frees memory but can slow down applications if it's increased too far (determining the sweet spot is basically iterative guestimation)

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for the idea. vfs_cache_pressure sort of works, but it’s not quite enough. Here’s what I did:

Comment: When I set vcp to 0, if I do a `find / -ls > /dev/null`, then spin down the disks, then `find` all the files again, the disks don't spin up. `free` shows buffers rising to about 202MB when doing this. But, if I do the `find`, then `cat /file/bigger/than/ram > /dev/null`, then `free` shows `cached` rising to fill the empty space, and for some reason `buffers` goes down to about 195MB. Then if I spin down the discs and do the `find` again the disks still spin up :-(

Comment: About `swappiness`: It’s set to the default of `60`, but the machine doesn’t have any swap partition, so I’m not sure if it does much. I guess I could put a swap file on the flash drive, but I’ve no idea how it would help, or how to size it.

Comment: By the way, guys, is there a way to tell the kernel something like “whatever you do, don’t use more than 2GB for caches”? I keep looking through the docs but I can’t seem to find anything that simple...

Comment: I'd leave the swap file out.  If you ever run out of memory and the Linux OOM (out of memory killer) runs you'll know you need swap.

Comment: Linux is trying to be smart about caching.  I'm not sure that setting vfs=0 will work the way you expect.  I think it would try to reclaim those other entries when pressure from applications (ie malloc()) request more memory.

As for a way to tell linux to not to use more then 2GB for caches, I'm unaware of such a thing.  It would be wasting RAM in most cases.

One other thing you might want to look at is "laptop mode" which attempts to do things differently to keep the disks spun down for laptops.  I haven't used it though, so I don't know much about it.

Comment: @JoelDavis Thanks for that comment. I was getting really worried while reading the answer (which was otherwise excellent and exactly what I was searching for) because swapping out the FS cache would be about the stupidest behaviour imaginable.

Comment: The keep is "*trying* to be smart". Sadly there's no well-known way to just increase the slab cache sizes to hold most attributes at the cost of the buffer cache; that would come pretty close to what you had wanted. Take 20M out of the buffer cache and use them for your most common directory indexes. Sorry, not anytime soon. :-)